# How does an e-cigarette dry tank protection sensor work?

Tags: resistance

E-cigarettes work with a resistance coil which heats liquid into vapor. Some e-cigs have a dry-tank protection, which senses when the coil does not have any liquid to heat, to avoid it getting too hot. My e-cig uses SAE 316L stainless steel resistance coils and is only tuned to protect for that specific type of coil.

How does the dry tank sensor work?

Comment: Could be anything from capacitive/resistive sensing to temperature control. At least post a picture with some serious zoom.

Comment: My guess would be the driver "senses" the lack of load as an increase in coil resistance (and thus temperature) beyond a "safe" limit.